# Imacro copy feature

Tags: csv, copy, clipboard

I need any other possible way for getting long description.

Still i am using Clipboard text for getting my data because my description field is too long which can not be taken through column reference {{!Col1}.

Is there any way to get text from any other source except csv and clipboard.

Thanks in advance.

`FORM=ID:reply_mebc_form ATTR=ID:body-msgForm CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}`

**'its copying text from clipboard**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is an option to read the whole file. But for that you have to use javascript scripting and some additional features. If you don't know how to use JS then you can close this question.